# how to use snort to track http/https sessions separately?

Tags: network, http, logging, snort, tracking

how can I use snort to breakdown http/https traffic into separate sessions and track each session separately and also dump them into separate log files or something that I can read from.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with snort, i.e. it is the wrong tool for this kind of job.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich afaik snort understands sessions, right? so why not?

Comment: snort understand TCP sessions but not HTTP sessions (and not TLS sessions). All these are different things. Given your question HTTP session is what you want to track - which can span multiple TCP sessions but a TCP session can also contain parts from different HTTP sessions. Also, snort does no SSL interception so HTTPS will not be analyzed.